# How to add an instance attribute to a subclass of webapp2.RequestHandler?

Tags: python, jinja2, webapp2, requesthandler

I have the following class definition:

```
class TestHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.msg = "hello world"
        self.render_form()     # modifies self.msg

    def post(self):
        print self.msg
        #...
        #...
        #...
        self.render_form()
```

When running, I get the following error:

File "/Users/mhalsharif/Desktop/wordsnet1/ascii-chan/main.py", line 129, in post
    print self.msg
AttributeError: 'AnswersHandler' object has no attribute 'msg'

I am simply trying to save a string in the 'msg' attribute and print it when post() is called. Why cannot I do that? and how to fix it?

Comment: You probably aren't handling the case when `post` is called without `get` and `self.msg` isn't yet defined.

Comment: I have added the statement: self.msg="hello first" in the constructor of TestHandler but post only print the initial value of self.msg (i.e. "hello first") and not "hello world". I checked the log console and get() is always called before post()!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

webapp2 will instantiate a new handler per each request it received, so there is no guarantee that if you set `self.something` in a request you will be able to retrieve the same value with another request, just because `self` will be a different object.

This is what happens in your case: the handlers that process your get and post requests are not the same instance, so `post` will not be able to read `self.msg` simply because it was never set first.

You can review the [docs](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/handlers.html) to have a better understanding on what is the lifecycle of a handler.

Comment: I though that something similar to this might have caused the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To pass data like your self.msg between request you have to use the datastore, cookies or the webapp2 app registry : http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/app.html#registry